# How to scrape a website which redirects for some time

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am trying to scrape a website which has a delay of 5 sec while displaying a ddos prevention page, the website is

[Koinex](https://koinex.in/)

I am using Python3 and BeuwtifulSoup, I think I would need to intrduce a time delayafter sending a request and before reading content.

Here is what I have done so far

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://koinex.in/'
response = requests.get(url)
html = response.content
```

Comment: it uses JavaScript to delay - but requests+BeautifulSoup can't run JavaScript. You may have to use `Selenium` to control web browser which runs JavaScript. It can also only delay and send to the same url with cookies to recognize if it is second request. Maybe if you will have those cookies then you can load it without delay. You may have to use `requests.Session()`

Comment: If I delete cookie `cf_clearance` then it shows ddos page again. So this cookie control this element.

Comment: @furas  please excuse my ignorance , so by using selenium if I delte the cf_clearance , I would be able to bypass the ddos page ?

Comment: no, it will be the opposite, if you get `cf_clearance` then you can bypass doss page. But using Selenium you don't have to do nothing because it will control browser so it will works like human using browser.

Comment: ohh and is it a variable or cookie name which I have to search for using selenium ?

Comment: can you share the script which you wrote or how you determined this, this will help in the future also

Comment: I used `DevTool` in Chrome/Firefox to see all requests sent from browser to server. After passing doss page I see cookies for this page - so I started deleting cookies and reloading page. When I deleted `cf_clearance` and reloaded then server sent again doss page. If I have `cf_clearance` then server doesn't send doss page again.

Comment: if you will use `Selenium` then you don't need to get  `cf_clearance` because browser will works the same way as when you use browser. It will display doss page, then it gets  `cf_clearance`  from server and later you can load any page in Selenium and search using Selenium's functions - ie. xpath, css selector, etc. You would need `cf_clearance` only if you want to use `BeautifulSoup`.

Comment: ohh, so if I can get/add cf_clearance to my beutifussoup code I can bypass the page, is it possible to do so or should I attempt this with Selenium only ?

Comment: page use JavaScript to generate some value and sends to special url and gets back ` cf_clearance` as cookies. This code not only generates different value but also use different functions to generate this value (sometimes it adds values, other time it substracts or divides, etc) so it could be problem to write in Python function which would generate this value - so it will be easier to use `Selenium` to uses browser which will load page and run JavaScript to generate value and request page which gets back `cf_clearance`

Answer (score 1):

It uses JavaScript to generate some value which is send to page `https://koinex.in/cdn-cgi/l/chk_jschl` and get cookie `cf_clearance` which is checked by page to skip doss page.

Code can generate value using different parameters and different methods in every requests so it can be easier to use Selenium to get data

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://koinex.in/')

time.sleep(8)

tables = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('table')

for item in tables:
    print(item.text)
    #print(item.get_attribute("value"))
```

Result

```
VOLUME PRICE/ETH
5.2310 64,300.00
0.0930 64,100.00
10.7670 64,025.01
0.0840 64,000.00
0.3300 63,800.00
0.2800 63,701.00
0.4880 63,700.00
0.7060 63,511.00
0.5020 63,501.00
0.1010 63,500.01
1.4850 63,500.00
1.0000 63,254.00
0.0300 63,253.00
VOLUME PRICE/ETH
1.0000 64,379.00
0.0940 64,380.00
0.9710 64,398.00
0.0350 64,399.00
0.7170 64,400.00
0.3000 64,479.00
5.1650 64,480.35
0.0020 64,495.00
0.2000 64,496.00
9.5630 64,500.00
0.4000 64,501.01
0.0400 64,550.00
0.5220 64,600.00
DATE VOLUME PRICE/ETH
31/12/2017, 12:19:29 0.2770 64,300.00
31/12/2017, 12:19:11 0.5000 64,300.00
31/12/2017, 12:18:28 0.3440 64,025.01
31/12/2017, 12:18:28 0.0750 64,026.00
31/12/2017, 12:17:50 0.0010 64,300.00
31/12/2017, 12:17:47 0.0150 64,300.00
31/12/2017, 12:15:45 0.6720 64,385.00
31/12/2017, 12:15:45 0.2000 64,300.00
31/12/2017, 12:15:45 0.0620 64,300.00
31/12/2017, 12:15:45 0.0650 64,199.97
31/12/2017, 12:15:45 0.0010 64,190.00
31/12/2017, 12:15:45 0.0030 64,190.00
31/12/2017, 12:15:25 0.0010 64,190.00
```

You can also get `HTML` from `Selenium` and use with `BeautifulSoup`

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)
```

but `Selenium` can get data using `xpath`, `css selector` and other methods so mostly there is no need to use `BeautifulSoup`

See documentation: [4. Locating Elements](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html)

---

**EDIT:** this code uses cookies from `Selenium` to load page with `requests` and it has no problem with DDoS page.

Problem is that page uses JavaScript to display tables so you can't get them using `requests`+`BeautifulSoup`. But maybe you will find urls used by JavaScript to get data for tables and then `requests` can be useful.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

# --- Selenium ---

url = 'https://koinex.in/'

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

time.sleep(8)

#tables = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('table')
#for item in tables:
#    print(item.text)

# --- convert cookies/headers from Selenium to Requests ---

cookies = driver.get_cookies()

for item in cookies:
    print('name:', item['name'])
    print('value:', item['value'])
    print('path:', item['path'])
    print('domain:', item['domain'])
    print('expiry:', item['expiry'])
    print('secure:', item['secure'])
    print('httpOnly:', item['httpOnly'])
    print('----')

# convert list of dictionaries into dictionary
cookies = {c['name']: c['value'] for c in cookies}

# it has to be full `User-Agent` used in Browser/Selenium (it can't be short 'Mozilla/5.0')
headers = {'User-Agent': driver.execute_script('return navigator.userAgent')}

# --- requests + BeautifulSoup ---

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = requests.Session()
s.headers.update(headers)
s.cookies.update(cookies)

r = s.get(url)

print(r.text)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
tables = soup.find_all('table')

print('tables:', len(tables))

for item in tables:
    print(item.get_text())
```

Comment: I add example how to get cookies from Selenium and use with requests.