# Redirection KeyError when scraping through iteration over website

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I'm trying to do scraping while looping over the websites contained in the column of a CSV file.

The problem is I'm getting :
**KeyError**: 'http://www.onisep.fr/http/redirection/metier/identifiant/10164'
which redirects to one of the links I'm interested in.

Here's my code :

```
for row in file:
    my_list = []
    dat_link = row['onisep link']
    requete = requests.get(row["{}".format(dat_link)])
    page = requete.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
    my_list.append(soup.find_all("span", "ezstring-field")[2].text.strip()) 
return my_list
```

I've done some research and tried [**time.sleep**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48040897/how-to-scrape-a-website-which-redirects-for-some-time), but that didn't solve my issue. Any idea on how to get rid of that error ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: This is a [KeyError](https://wiki.python.org/moin/KeyError). This means that in this line of code: `requete = requests.get(row["{}".format(dat_link)])` you are accessing an invalid key of a `dict`.

Answer (score 0):

`dat_link` is string URL not a key, use it directly.

```
dat_link = row['onisep link']
requete = requests.get(dat_link)
```